# Unable to find text box control on few machine only using coded ui

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-7, coded-ui-tests

We are using Coded UI Tests with VSTS 2012 Ultimate.
We are facing issue to identify a Text Box control which has spell check feature for words typed into the control. This does not happen on every machine, we tried to find if any variable need to set so that it get identified but no use. We found nothing and we are stuck with it.

Please let me know if you have come across any such situation and what could be possible to this solution.

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 has a spell checking feature embedded . Is this [switched on](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/turn-spell-check-internet-explorer-77614.html) or off?

Comment: How about the loading time in different machine is it same ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the visual studio 2012 has update 4 installed. It was an issue with coded UI where it was not able to recognize the control based on search criteria. Updating it solved the problem for me.

Comment: We are able to identify the control but not able to add or edit text into it. We verified it manually and it was working fine on same machine where it was failed.

Answer (score -1):

//Password Email

```
        UITestControl uIPassword = new UITestControl(browser);
        uIPassword .TechnologyName = "Web";
        uIPassword .SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Edit");
        uIPassword .SearchProperties.Add("id", "login-password");

        Keyboard.SendKeys(UIPassword, "test001");
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer, as it stands it is not very useful